# XMLHttpRequest.open third parameter false not give php mysql query result on iPad

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using below for AJAX

```
var myRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open("POST", "abc.php", false);
```

So when it's false & i do database connection in PHP (abc.php file) & run query it gives result number of rows 1 on desktop. But not on iPad.

When i changed it to

```
myRequest.open("POST", "abc.php", true);
```

In iPad as well on desktop it will give number of rows as 1. **By making it false why mysql query not give result in AJAX file on iPad?**

Comment: The third argument is actually being deprecated, that is synchronous ajax is, so it should ***ALWAYS*** be set to `true` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter on the `open()` method of the XML HTTP request defines of the XML HTTP request should be `async` or not. An asynchronous call doesn't wait for other calls (synchronous) to invoke.

Comment: That i know http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp. But by making it false why it's not working on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter specifies whether the request made is asynchronous or a synchronous request..To be specific about syncronous and asynchronous request

Synchronous -- The script execution gets stopped and will only proceed when you get back a reply from the server

Asynchronous--Here the script will the processed and will not wait for a reply..When there is a reply your page will be updated with a specific result.

In most caes recommend to use aynchronous calls,because even it the server side call returns any error the whole web page do not break.